# Spectral Norm Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

I don't really understand the question below:

A matrix can have small eigenvalues but large spectral norm (i.e., largest singular value). Find such a matrix A of proper dimension so that all of its eigenvalues λ satisfy |λ| < 0.5, but its spectral norm satisfies ||A|| ≥ K for some K > 0 that can be made arbitrarily large.

I feel like I need to start with the definition of the spectral norm:
$$||A||=\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)}$$

Not really sure if that's the right place to start or where to go from there. Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Start with $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and find
$\|A\| = 1$. Then $\| K A \| = |K|$. All eigenvalues are zero.

Comment: $||KA|| =|K|$ but how does that prove that $||A||\geq K$?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Pick $K$. Then choose the matrix $KA$, which has eigenvalues that satisfy $|\lambda| < {1 \over 2}$ and $\|KA\|  = K$. If you would rather, pick $K$ then define $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & K \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Same effect.

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes sense....In hindsight it's a pretty simple problem.